# android drawing on a view

Tags: android, view, draw

I try to creare a custom view for circle progress, I draw some points on draw, than I want to crow something over this point while the progress increases, this is my code:

```
public SpinnerView(Context context) {
            super(context);       
    }
        @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            float x = 0;
            float y = 0;

            for(int i=0; i<360; i = i + 12){

                x = (float) (view.getWidth()/2 + 260 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)));
                y = (float) (view.getHeight()/2 + 260 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)));

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawCircle((float) x, (float) y, 10, paint);
            }   
            viewCanvas = canvas;
        }

        public void updateWithProgress (int progress){

            // progress : total = x : 36

            int point = (360*progress)/total;
            point = point/12;

            Log.d("point" + point,"-------");

            float x = (float) (view.getWidth()/2 + 260 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(point)));
            float y = (float) (view.getHeight()/2 + 260 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(point)));

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            viewCanvas.drawCircle( x,  y, 20, paint);
        }
    }
```

the problem is that the updateWithProgress not work, it don't draw the blue circle over the old red circle.

Comment: where do you call "updateWithProgress"?

Comment: inside an async task, it was call because I see Log.d("point" + point,"-------");

Comment: Try invalidating (call `invalidate();` on view) the view after calling that updateWithProgress..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approach here isn't right. You can't update the view in a different thread by saving the canvas on the 1st iteration, then update it on a seperate thread. All your UI updates should happen on the UI thread during the onDraw method call.

Here's my suggestion:

1. Hold an instance member called "progress", add a getter and setter for progress.
2. Move all the code in your "updateWithProgress" method to your "onDraw" method, where the "progress" instance member will replace the parameter.
3. Whenever the progress needs to be updated, change the progress value via the getter / setter & call `postInvalidate` on the view.

This should get you started.